# JSON Response keeps coming back undefined (ajax file upload)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, file-upload

I'm currently using Valum's Ajax File uploader to do same-page file uploads. For my script, I need to pass the final file path (after it gets uploaded) back to the client-side and store it in a variable, however, I keep getting "undefined" for responseJSON['filename']. I've tried tons of different solutions and nothing seems to work (changed datatype from json to text, played around with the way PHP sent the response, etc. etc.)

There must be something simple I'm overlooking here....

All help is welcome. Thanks!

EDIT: JS is here: http://jsfiddle.net/acw9V/ for the PHP portion, I'm using the default PHP code in Valum's zip archive.

Update: still no luck... keep getting back undefined from responseJSON. I'm wondering if there's some way to just return whatever message is echo'd in PHP, maybe I could work with that?

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: Yeah, here's the main JS: http://jsfiddle.net/acw9V/ It uploads files fine, I just can't get it to return a proper path...

Comment: How about checking the response object's content, just to see what exactly you're getting back: `console.log(responseJSON);`

Comment: Console isn't even showing any output :(

Answer (score 0):

I think that 'responseJSON' in fact is **STRING** , not an array. (assuming that you just echo-ing your output in php and you cannot echo array) To be treated as array, after receiving, responseJSON should be eval-ed.

var data = eval(responseJSON);

(eventually: var data = eval ("(" + responseJSON + ")");  )

then data['filename'] should contain uploaded file name (if this was specified in php)